# Rational approximation on rotation invariant compact subsets of complex plane

Tags: cv.complex-variables

What does the Vitushkin's theorem say about the equality $A(K) = R(K)$ in the special case when $K$ is rotation invariant? More precisely, what are necessary and/or sufficient conditions on $\{|k|: k \in K\}$ for the equality above?

Answer (score 2):

I think that for rotation invariant compact $K$ the condition $A(K)=R(K)$ is always true. 
Vitushkin's criterion required to show that (using notations in Gamelin "Uniform algebras" Chapter VIII)
$$\limsup_{\delta\to 0}\frac{\alpha(\Delta(z,\delta)\setminus \mathrm{int}\, K)}{\alpha(\Delta(z,\delta)\setminus K)}<\infty$$
for every $z$ in the boundary of $K$. It's more simple to estimate analytic capacity $\gamma$ than continuous analytic capacity $\alpha$.
They agree for open sets, so $\alpha(\Delta(z,\delta)\setminus K)=\gamma(\Delta(z,\delta)\setminus K)\ge \delta/4$.
That's because $\alpha(\Delta(z,\delta)\setminus K)$ contains an arc of circle (with the center at $0$) of length at least $\delta$ (there are arcs arbitrary closed to $z$) and $\gamma$ of such arc is at least $\delta/4$. This is were rotation invariance is used.
Finally $\alpha(\Delta(z,\delta)\setminus K)\le \alpha(\Delta(z,\delta))=\delta$, thus the limit is less than 4.